# What language string determines the 'group name' of menu items for a component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I'm trying to change the text content of the 'menu item group' name in the Admin backend for my component:

[image: Joomla 3.x menu item selector]

You an see in this image it's set to **milocvs** (the component I'm building is called `com_milocvs`).

What JText constant do I need to set, and where (`.sys.ini` or `.ini`), to change this to be something nicer (e.g. **Milo CVS**)? I've set the `COM_MILOCVS` in both `...sys.ini` and `...ini` and having looked at the other stock components I can't see anywhere else this would be set.

Comment: If the answer below have solved your issue, then consider to accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

The menutypes view gets the components names from the name column of the extensions table. From your screenshot I can see that in the database the name of your component is given as milocvs, instead of the com_milocvs. That's why the language constant cannot work. 
As for the rest, if you fix the name of the component, a lang constant at the sys.ini file will work for this.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I can see this in MySQL. How can I fix the name of the component? At what point is the name added to the extensions table? Is there a best practice here - in my manifest file I have `<extension...><name>Milo CVS</name>...</extension>`

Comment: How have you installed it currently?

Comment: Packaged up into zip with manifest file, through the web uploader, `method="upgrade"`

Comment: hmmm, usually that would be the name field in the XML file.

Comment: Yeah - did a clean install as well on a site that had never seen the component, still the same problem...

Comment: what do you have for name in the name field of component's xml file?

Comment: `<name>Milo CVS</name>`

Comment: Man there you need to write your constant for the database. Change this to com_milocvs or whatever is your component...

Comment: Derppp. Cheers!